# What steps should I follow environment variables in Mac for Android?

Tags: android, macos, react-native, environment-variables

I am just starting out in the Mac world and recently joined the developer program.
My intention is to terminate an application with React Native.

The problem is that I don't know how to configure the environment variables in my Catalina 10.15.4.
I have Googled.
I have installed the independent SDKs and had errors.

Install Android Studio and it also had errors.

The bottom line seemed to be that I never found the PATH I have chosen to remove everything from my system and start again.

What documentation has worked for you to configure the Mac environment for Android?

Can you help me find documentation to read and study documentation? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew is a package manager that makes installing things on Mac easier.
https://brew.sh/

Install homebrew

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Install android studio with Homebrew

```
brew cask install android-studio
```

Comment: AndreasSteffensen  Thanks for your input, but how do I configure the environment variables?
Installing Visual Studio is no problem